# Exponentiate linear regression coefficient using the gtsummary package

Tags: gtsummary

I want to exponentiate my loge values in the gtsummary package but I am getting error when I said exponentiate= TRUE.

Can someone kindly help me?

*mu <- lm(log(iron)~ treatment + log(erythroferrone)+ log(epo)+ log(crp)+ log(hepciden), data=endline1) %>% tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE)%>% as_gt() theme_gtsummary_journal(journal = "nejm")*

*Error in tidy_and_attach(., tidy_fun = tidy_fun, conf.int = conf.int, : exponentiate = TRUE is not valid for this type of model*.

Comment: the error message says you cannot use `exponentiate = TRUE` for your type of model. you are running a linear model with a log outcome and not a model where you can/should exponentiate the beta coefficients

Comment: gtsummary uses `broom::tidy()` in the background, and I think it's (correctly) messaging you to NOT exponentiate coefs from a linear model.